# django, external api - model or view

Tags: django, api

I'm creating django app without frontend (admin panel only). Application should use external api.

Example: add, remove and edit any item should do some actions with external api (something like synchronization).

Where should I keep code using this api? Is model is appropriate place? Should I override *save* method?

Comment: you could likely use models (so that you can get the admin features) and just override each of the models create/save/delete methods. as I believe the admin panel is always tied to a model (so will not display if you don't have a model).

Comment: Depends on what you mean by an external api. If your API will be accessed through HTTP, you're probably building this through views, even though no human will "view" the information directly. API views are only special in that they may return JSON or XML instead of HTML.

Comment: You might look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ or tastypie

Comment: @dylrei, I'm not building an api, I'm going to use external api in my app. It's not answer for my question, but your thinking is actually good.

Comment: @joelgoldstick, look my comment up there ^

Comment: @MateuszJagiełło Ah, OK. You're __consuming__ an API, not __providing__ one. In that case, your model code is probably the easiest choice.